# Integral of $x^2 e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, error-function

Like the title says, I'm trying to find

$$\int_0^r x^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx$$

Where $r$ is some finite value.

I've done one step using integration by parts with $u=x^2$ and $dv=e^{-x^2}dx$, which has left me with

$$\left.x^2 \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt\,\right|_0^r - \int_0^r 2x \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt\,dx$$

and more questions than answers. I'm aware that the integrals in $t$ are a scaling of the error function, and don't have a representation in elementary functions. For the second term in this I think I should try another integration by parts, but then I would need the integral of the error function, and am not sure how to get that either.

Am I going about this the right way? What do I do next?

Comment: Wolfram says you don't need the integral of the error function, but I don't know what the derivation is. http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E2+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29+dx&x=0&y=0

Comment: One trick is to take $I(r,t) = \int_0^r e^{-tx^2}{\rm d}x$. This function can be expressed via the error function (after a substitution). Now $\frac{\partial I}{\partial t} = - \int_0^r x^2 e^{-tx^2}{\rm d}x$ which for $t=1$ is your integral.

Comment: @Winther that's a super cool trick!

Comment: @StellaBiderman It's quite useful to know as it can be used to solve a whole number of integrals: for example $\int_0^\infty x^k e^{-x}{\rm d}x$ can be solved by evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} {\rm d}x$ and differentiating $k$ times. See e.g. [this](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf) and [this](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf) for other examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can solve the integral using a nice little trick (often called [Feynman integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)). We generalize the problem by adding a free parameter to the exponential (the reason we do this is that $\frac{d}{dt} e^{-tx^2} = -x^2 e^{-tx^2}$ which for $t=1$ is the integrand we are trying to evaluate). We start by defining the function

$$f(t,r) \equiv \int_0^r e^{-tx^2}{\rm d}x$$

Now observe that

$$\frac{\partial f(t,r)}{\partial t} = -\int_0^r x^2 e^{-tx^2}{\rm d}x \implies  \int_0^r x^2 e^{-x^2}{\rm d}x = \left[-\frac{\partial f(t,r)}{\partial t}\right]_{t=1}$$

Substituting $y = \sqrt{t}x$ we can evaluate $f$ in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) as
$$f(t,r) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(r \sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$

and by differentiating and taking $t=1$ we get the result
$$\int_0^r x^2 e^{-x^2}{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(r)-\frac{1}{2} e^{-r^2} r$$

Answer (score 2):

Since we have can analytically integrate

$$\int xe^{-x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$$

you can use integration by parts with $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$ and $g(x) = x$ to obtain

$$
\int_0^r x^2e^{-x^2}\ dx = \left[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}x\right]_{x=0}^r-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^re^{-x^2}  
$$

The last part can be expressed with the error function.